# How to replace opening and closing curly braces {{ }} with pattern {{ '{{' }} / {{ '}}' }} in Python/Ansible

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

We are using Ansible for templating grafana dashboards exported in JSON file. The dashboard JSON may have dashboard variable references like {{ region }}, {{ state }} etc in many places within the Json. When running the templating code, we are getting variable not defined for 'region', 'state' variables. We want the ansible to ignore these variables and print as it is along with curly braces. We came across two solutions

1. Use {% raw %} {% endraw %}
2. Replace {{ with {{ '{{' }} and replace }} with {{ '}}' }} in the json

We tried #1 and it didn't work. Our jinja2 template looks as below

```
{
  "dashboard": {{ item.json | indent(width=2) | trim }} ,{{ "\n" }}
  {%- if 'folder_uid' in item %}
  "folderUid": "{{ item.folder_uid }}",{{ "\n" }}
  {%- endif %}
  "overwrite": true
}
```

in the above item.json variable contains the dashboard json data

we tried all the following

- {% raw %} {{ item.json | indent(width=2) | trim }} {% endraw %}
- "{% raw %} {{ item.json | indent(width=2) | trim }} {% endraw %}"
- {% raw %} '{{ item.json | indent(width=2) | trim }}' {% endraw %}
- {% raw %} "{{ item.json | indent(width=2) | trim }}" {% endraw %}

nothing worked. ansible still tries to template the json content

So, we are trying #2. Can anyone help how can we replace {{ with {{ '{{' }} and replace }} with {{ '}}' }} patterns? the issue is we can't do simple text replace because replacing {{ also introduces }}.

Comment: No one can help you without an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), but the presence of `item` there makes me suspect you're using `with_items:` which one needs to be extra cautious about since ansible will attempt to resolve jinja2 mustaches every place it can, and looping makes that harder to reason about

Answer (score 2):

I think you can avoid expanding the curly braces by including the JSON attribute(s) in the Ansible template. For example, given the *"grafana dashboard exported in JSON file"*

```
shell> cat test-152.json
{
  "dashboard": "region {{ region }} state {{ state }}"
}
```

Include the JSON data in a dictionary, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        content: "{{ lookup('file', 'test-152.json') }}"
```

creates the dictionary *content*

```yaml
  content:
    dashboard: region {{ region }} state {{ state }}
```

Next create an Ansible template and reference the attribute of
the *"dashboard JSON (that) may have dashboard variable references like {{ region }}, {{ state }})"*

```yaml
shell> cat test-152.txt.j2
# Grafana dashboard created by Ansible
# Created {{ '%Y-%m-%d' | strftime }}
{{ content.dashboard }}
```

The Ansible task

```yaml
    - template:
        src: test-152.txt.j2
        dest: test-152.txt
```

creates the file

```yaml
shell> cat test-152.txt
# Grafana dashboard created by Ansible
# Created 2021-08-05
region {{ region }} state {{ state }}
```

Fit the template to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The Ansible [template module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html) includes `variable_end_string` and `variable_start_string` parameters that might help you with this.  You can replace `{{` and `}}` with `<<` and `>>` for example.